# Imagemagick - change policy.xml on Heroku

Tags: heroku, https, imagemagick, policy, node-imagemagick

I'm trying to access images via https on Heroku with Imagemagick. How can I change the policies (in policy.xml) on Heroku?

Heroku made an "ImageMagick security update" in May, 2016: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/891

I can see the policy list, after typing `heroku run bash` and `convert -list policy`:

`Path: [built-in]
  Policy: Undefined
    rights: None`

`Path: /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml
[...]
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: HTTPS
[...]`

How can I change the policy?

**update 1:** this is the error in the log file:

`` Command failed: convert.im6: not authorized `//scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13962741_132344500547278_4974691444630710043_n.jpg?oh=c169b4ffce9e5ce330ee99214cc6b8d5&oe=5880F245' ``

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve found a relatively simple solution.

Create a `.magick` directory in your app’s source, and add your `policy.xml` there. Then, you’ll have to set the environment variable `MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH` to `/app/.magick` in order to load your file with higher precedence than the default one.

Comment: This is documented in Heroku's help docs too: https://help.heroku.com/RFDJQSG3/how-can-i-override-imagemagick-settings-in-a-policy-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

We need to install the third party software ImageMagick on heroku. I used this https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick build pack for installing ImageMagick.

So, inside bin/compile, there is a policy file, which is restricting the images to read over Https, enable the attribute `rights` to `read` which allows to read over Https

Fork the repo and do your changes, commit and add that repository url to your heroku buildpacks

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. `MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH` does not work with the default installation of ImageMagick on heroku.

Comment: @thejayerramareddy @agatheblues i tried this solution (see changes: https://github.com/mgiraldo/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick/blob/master/bin/compile#L63) and am still getting `attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy 'HTTPS'`. `heroku run convert -list policy` displays Read rights for Coder in pattern HTTPS. any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Read the warnings at [ImageTragick](https://imagetragick.com/), then make a backup and delete the line that restricts you.

You can find the file to edit in the same directory as the other XML config files by doing the following - the file is called `policy.xml`:

```
convert -debug configure -list font 2>&1 | grep -E "Searching|Loading"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I only know the ImageMagick side of things and don't use heroku myself. Hopefully, this will give someone who knows heroku enough of a clue as to what to do.

Comment: To the down-voter... you might have the courtesy to explain the down-vote so that I, and others, can learn what is so unacceptable about my attempt to assist.

Comment: You just repeated my problem, doesn't you?

Comment: No, I told you how to find the `policy.xml` file, which was useful information not in your original question before you just edited it, and I also told you *how* to change the file (by deleting the line) once you located it - which appeared to me to be what you were asking - given that your question was *"How can I change the policy?"*. At the very worst you could have ignored my answer if you felt it didn't add much, rather than kicking someone in the teeth who is trying to help out.

Comment: that's not true. this was my first version: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39425446/1

Comment: What's not true? Your original question clearly did not contain the path of the `policy.xml` file, nor did it give any indication that you might have known  that the solution would be to delete the line which prevented access. I thought either of those aspects might help you and rather than a polite *"thank you"*, you chose to down vote my answer.

Comment: I don't have time for this discussion here. Thanks for your try to help. It doesn't helped me, but for other user, your answer looked like "ah, someone helped him". Thats why I voted down, to signal, that this answer doesn't helped me a single bit. I want to focus on my problem and not to fight with you for your ego